# How to switch from one sheet to all the other sheets and get their values in excel using java

Tags: java, arrays, excel, switch-statement, apache-poi

I am developing a java code which uses excel as source, I will tell my problem using small example I am having four sheets in my excel a,b,c,d. 'a' is the home page and all the other three are dependent on 'a'values, because the names of the values from 'a' is same as  the names of the sheets b,c,d. Now depending on the values I should switch to other sheets(b,c,d) and fetch their value.

So now I have to switch to other sheets and get values from the sheets(b,c,d). Please help with this problem

Comment: And where exactly is the problem? [Workbook](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html) provides all the needed methods. It has a iterator for all the sheets which can be got using method `sheetIterator()`. And it provides `getSheet(java.lang.String name)` as well as `getSheetAt(int index)` to get single sheets directly.

Comment: can you give me in code on your point of you, how to switch to other sheets (not single sheet) using sheet iterator

Comment: [Iterate over rows and cells](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator) also shows iterating over sheets. `for (Sheet sheet : wb ) {...`.